# Is there a term describing "doing activities", in relation to mental health?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Im trying to find a connection between mental health outcomes and how much stimulation people have. Particular in reference to older adults.

The extreme being sitting doing nothing.

The problem is that I havent been able to find any studies if I use the word "stimulation", so Im wondering if theres a more appropriate term?

Comment: It's possible to stimulate someone whilst they're sitting doing nothing, but since you discount that, could you describe what you actually mean by "stimulation". There are some links to previous questions which might interest you and help you focus the question: [1](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/exercise-for-mental-health), [2](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/whats-the-optimal-type-of-exercise-to-increase-bdnf), [3](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/does-meditation-improve-working-memory-more-than-exercise).

Comment: I'd expect studies to be more explicit about what the "activities" are, so they'd name them by those activities rather than the sort of broad term you're looking for.